# Kernel dying due to memory issues, why?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, garbage-collection, databricks

I've created the following function

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import numpy as np

def my_func():
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randn(1000000, 100)
    )
    y = spark.createDataFrame(dd) # 10 X 1k
    y2 = y.select(F.sum(F.col("1")))
    y3 = y2.collect()
    y2.unpersist(blocking=True)
    y2 = None
    return y3
```

That I run in the following manner

```py
list_of_results = []
for i in range(100):
    list_of_results.append(my_func())
```

From what I've read about Spark/Java GC, I'm not expecting this to fail due to memory issues. Yet, it fails after 84 iterations.

```
Fatal error: The Python kernel is unresponsive.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Python process exited with an unknown exit code.
```

The memory usage of up until this point looks kind of how I'd expect it to look:

[image]

The active memory of the cluster is 28 GB (2 workers @ 14GB)

Comment: what is `_y` used in your func?

Comment: Apologies, was the incorrect name of the y2 variable. @samkart

Comment: what's the relationship between `df` and `a`?

Comment: you create a dataframe of 1000000x100, but use a single column -- why create 100 columns?

Comment: @JonathanLam `a` is the same as `df`. I’ve updated it.

Comment: @samkart It’s an artificial problem for testing and understanding memory management in databricks.